# A permutation with reflection property

Tags: finite-groups, permutations, permutation-groups

Consider permutations $\pi$ of the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ having the symmetry property $\pi \pi^* \pi = \pi^*$, where $\pi^*$ is the "reflection" $k \mapsto n+1-k$.  Are there references or other information about such a $\pi$?

Comment: You really do mean $\pi\pi^*\pi$, not $\pi\pi^*\pi^{-1}$?

Comment: Also, is $\pi^*$ meant to depend on $\pi$, say as $k \mapsto n + 1 - \pi(k)$, or is it really a fixed permutation independent of $\pi$?  If the latter, then you are just looking for permutations conjugate by a fixed involution to their inverses.

Comment: In other words, $\pi \pi^{*} $ is involution. It should reduce the questions about your permutations to the questions about involutions.

Comment: @FedorPetrov's re-phrasing is better than mine.

Comment: I really mean $\pi^*\pi\pi^*$. And $\pi^*$ is what I defined, a fixed permutation independent of $\pi$. Thanks for the hint about involutions!

Comment: Sorry, I really mean $\pi\pi^*\pi$, as in the original posting. Sorry about the confusion...

Comment: Why don't you use a notation without the letter $\pi$ to denote the reflection?

Comment: The notation $\pi^*$ is a bit misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem boils down to finding permutations $\pi$ such that $\pi(n+1-x)=y\iff\pi(n+1-y)=x$. Let $X\subset\{1,...,n\}$ be such that $n-\lvert X\rvert$ is even and let $P$ be a partition of $\{1,...,n\}\backslash X$ into pairs and denote, for every element $k$ of $\{1,...,n\}\backslash X$, its companion by $P(k)$. Then, the permutation defined by $\pi(n+1-k)=P(k)$ for every $k\in\{1,...,n\}\backslash X $ and $\pi(n+1-x)=x$ for every $x\in X$ satisfies the required condition.  It is clear that appropriate permutations are in a one-to-one correspondence with $(X,P)$ couples.

Comment: Isn't this just a complicated way of saying "$\pi$ is of the form $\sigma\pi^*$, where $\sigma$ is an involution" (which is what @FedorPetrov's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310425/a-permutation-with-reflection-property#comment773715_310425)'s that you quote says)?  I guess it depends on the poster's needs which form of the statement is more convenient ….

Comment: I thought a constructive/descriptive approach might be helpful depending on the OP's needs indeed. I just lightened my response a bit.

Comment: By the way, as a TeX matter, `\mid` is only intended as a binary operator (like `2 \mid 6`: $2 \mid 6$).  For delimiters, you want `\lvert` and `\rvert` (like `\lvert2\rvert`:  $\lvert2\rvert$).  I made the edit here.